# Read jpeg file in Python, encode it into Unicode and put it into protobuf

Tags: python, unicode, protocol-buffers

I am transferring an image from a python backend to a c++ backend. I chose Google protobuf, with the following simple structure:

```
message data {
  optional string image = 1;
}
```

I then use Python to read the image and put it into the image field:

```
data = server_pb2.data()
data.image = (open(image_fn).read())
```

But protobuf complains with the following message:

> Value Error: [hex data] has type str, but isn't in 7-bit ASCII encoding. Non-ASCII strings must be converted to unicode objects before being added.

I have tried several ways to make the data unicode but without success.

Maybe somebody has encountered this problem before? Or is there a better way to transfer image data?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't "encode" binary into Unicode - that is using the encoder backwards and the result is not defined. She http://tiny.cc/io - you should (as over the answer here) just store the binary directly

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to read an image into a `bytes` field and forgot i needed to `.read()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `bytes` as the type in the .proto file rather than `string`.

`bytes` is used for an arbitrary sequence of bytes (eg an image). `string` is used for a sequence of UTF-8 or ASCII characters (eg text).